# How to listen for "visible" property of Window in Swing/AWT?

Tags: java, swing, awt, windowstate

There is a bean property "visible", which is represented by getter `isVisible()` and setter `setVisible()` in class `Window`.

How to listen for this value?

I would like to implement popular "view" menu with check box with binding library. Unfortunately I can't see how to bind "visible" property of a window. Even I can't write translator, because I see no any predefined way to listen for this property:

```
package tests;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class Try_Swing2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                    frame2.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {

                            System.out.println("windowState.newState = " + e.getNewState());


                        }
                    });

                    frame2.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowOpened");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowIconified");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowDeiconified");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowDeactivated");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowClosing");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowClosed");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("windowActivated");
                        }
                    });

                    frame2.addPropertyChangeListener("visible", new PropertyChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            System.out.println("visible = " + evt.getNewValue());
                        }
                    });

                    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

                    frame2.setTitle("This window is controlled by another window");

                    frame2.setSize(800, 600);
                    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame2.setVisible(true);

                    AbstractAction toggleAction = new AbstractAction("Toggle another window visibility") {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            frame2.setVisible( !frame2.isVisible() );
                        }

                    };


                    JButton toggleButton = new JButton(toggleAction);

                    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();

                    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    frame1.setTitle("This windows controls");
                    frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    frame1.add(toggleButton);


                    frame1.pack();
                    frame1.setLocation(0, 0);
                    frame1.setVisible(true);




                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: _a bean property "visible"_ no, its not a bean property. You'll need an adapter that listens to windowEvents and maps them to a bean property, then bind your client to that adapter

Comment: You can use a `ComponentListener` and override `componentShown` and `componentHidden`. It's similar in nature

Answer (score 3):

The `visible` property is not really bound to the `WindowsListener`, but to the `ComponentListener` because it belong to the `Component` class, not the `Window` class.

In order to listen to changes in the `visible` property, the `componentShown(ComponentEvent e)` method of the `ComponentListener` needs to be implemented. It is always easier to inherit from the adapters, so in this case:

```
frame2.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Component is Visible");
    }
});
```

The adapters have empty implementations of the listeners, e.g. `ComponentAdapter` class which has empty implementations of the methods in `ComponentListener`, and `WindowAdapter` from `WindowListener`.

For more details, see [Component Adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentAdapter.html), [Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html), and  [How to Write a Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and

Answer (score 2):

The [method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addPropertyChangeListener%28java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyChangeListener%29) for `Component.addPropertyChangeListener` clearly lists the properties that are being observed. The visibility state is not listed. And as a `JFrame` (or one of its super classes up to `Component`) does not add any new behavior, you cannot observe changes to the visibility state on a `JFrame`.

However, you could subclass `JFrame` with overriding the `setVisible` method. In this new implementation you can fire such a property change:

```
public class VisibleAwareFrame extends JFrame {
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        boolean visible = isVisible();
        super.setVisible(b);
        firePropertyChange("visible", visible, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: subclassing is sub-optimal - and won't help if the frame isn't fully under the control of the binding code. Instead, use an adapter (that's my tag line of today ;-) which maps windowEvents to proper bean properties. Also, the firing is incorrect as you can't know if the new visible really is b after calling super - as a general rule, always query for the new property when firing

Comment: What adapters are you speaking all the day? Why are you keeping a secret?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose will this react on pressing cross by mouse?

Comment: @kleopatra You are completely right. Was a quick solution, I thought of. SuzanCioc: He told about a WindowAdapter added to a JFrame, whose methods will be called by the windowing system. Such a method call will tell you what happened.

Comment: the `visible` property is not part of the `Window` class but the [`Component` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JFrame.html). Therefore the correct listener to use is `ComponentListener` that has the `componentShown` method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Global AWT Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/)**

```
long eventMask = AWTEvent.COMPONENT_EVENT_MASK;

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
        String paramString = e.paramString();
        System.out.println(paramString);
    }
}, eventMask);
```

Here is the some outputs

```
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_HIDDEN
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_RESIZED (4,23 492x473)
COMPONENT_MOVED (4,23 492x473)
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 492x473)
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_MOVED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_SHOWN
COMPONENT_MOVED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_MOVED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 500x500)
COMPONENT_HIDDEN
COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 494x475)
COMPONENT_MOVED (0,0 494x475)
```

You can put checks on source as well as event type on `paramString`. Check for `COMPONENT_HIDDEN` and `COMPONENT_SHOWN` event and based on event change or set the `visible` property.
It might help you.